# unable to load multiple images in jspdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to load multiple images which generates dynamically. I want to convert those images into PDF format.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
   <input type='submit' id='test' style='align:center' value='Generate'>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script to generate pdf using jspdf is:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
      var t = document.getElementById("test"); 
      t.addEventListener("click", sayHi, false);
      function sayHi(){
        var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
            var img = new Image();

            img.onError = function() {
                alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
            };
            img.onload = function() {
                callback(img);
            };
            img.src = url;
        }
    var doc = new jsPDF();  
    var length = <?php echo count($items); ?>; /* $items id from php which is an array of items */
    var cnt=0; /* using this variable to get the end of the loop */
    <?php
        foreach($items as $item)
        {?>
            cnt++;
            getImageFromUrl('http://localhost:800/prod/chart.php?period=<?php echo $timeperiod; ?>&stime=<?php echo $startingtime; ?>&itemids=<?php echo $item->itemid; ?>&type=0&updateProfile=1&profileIdx=web.item.graph&width=1222&screenid=&curtime=1442486527893', function(imgData) {
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 150, 75); 
                /* Initiall tried here to save pdf file and as a result n number of pdf's are downloading with same image */
                /* doc.save('out.pdf'); */

            }
            );

        <?php 
        }
         ?>
     if(cnt==length)
            {
                /* after trying in for loop i tried here as a result i got only one pdf but with out images */
                doc.save('out.pdf');
            }
      } 
}
</script>
```

Below are the methods I have tried:

1. Tried to generate keep all the images in a div tag and generate PDF using that div tag.
2. Thought images are loaded synchronously and decided to wait till the image creation is completed and generate PDF. This time I am getting only a single PDF but with no images.
3. Tried to convert image into base 64 and display it, but no luck

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Problem here is I am overriding the image. As soon as I change X and Y co-ordinates in doc.addImage function its working.

But Jspdf is taking much space. for 48 pages it is taking close to 15MB which is very high. Need to work on decreasing the size.

Thanks to all who worked on this.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer this example for one image and same way you can do for multiple images:

```
 var img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {
    var dataURI = getBase64Image(img);
    return dataURI;

}
img.src = "../Images/UW_DriveLogo.jpg";

function getBase64Image(img) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

}
```

then you can simply call load method:

```
 doc.addImage(img.onload(), 'PNG', doc.internal.pageSize.width - 75, 0, 75, 75);
```

Comment: Welcome buddy :)